# How to Uncheck Radio button in Wpd DataGrid Coloumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have a problem i m using Wpf datagrid my one Column i s radio button(item template column) Coloumn when i m select another Row Radio Button my First One IS Still Check And i want it is to be uncheck How can i Achive it

thanks

if there is Multiple row in A grid i want to select only one

Comment: It would help if you posted your current code, so any possible errors in it can be spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the Radio buttons in Same Group.  Add the GroupName="DataGridChkBoxes" to the Checkbox control.